# Spectral Mapping Theorem in Continuous Functional Calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $A$ be a bounded self adjoint operator and $f$ be a continuous fucntion on $\sigma(A)$.
Let $\lambda \in \mathrm{Ran}(f)$. Prove that there are $\psi\in H,$ with $\|\psi\|=1$ and $\|(f(A)-\lambda)\psi\|$ arbitrarily small so that $\lambda \in \sigma(f(A))$.

This is an exercise from Reed & Simons' book chap 7, Q8.

I have managed to show the existence of $\psi$, but I am stuck at showing that leads to $\lambda \in \sigma(f(A))$. I am wondering if anyone could help me with that?

Comment: What's $H$ here? The Hilbert space that is the domain and co-domain of $H$?

Comment: H is a Hilbert space here. A is an operator on H

Comment: Apparently you've answered yourself, but I'm curious about the question. What's $f(A)$ if $f : \sigma(A) \to \mathbb C$ (I presumed the codomain of $f$ here)? The notation confuses me.

Comment: We define f(A) to be a bounded linear operator associated with the continuosu function f on $\sigma(A)$.  You can have a look of the continuos linear functional. https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~vybiral/FAII/FAII_Skript.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I might have solved it by my own.
We will prove it by contradiction. Since we have shown the existence of $\psi.$ Then, we can find a sequence $\psi_n$ with $\|\psi_n\|=1$ and $\|(f(A)-\lambda) \psi_n\|\rightarrow 0.$
Assume $\lambda\in \rho(f(A)),$ then $(f(A)-\lambda)^{-1}$ is bounded.
$$
1 = \|\psi_n\|
= \|(f(A)-\lambda)^{-1}(f(A)-\lambda)\psi_n\| \\
\leq \|(f(A)-\lambda)^{-1}\|\|(f(A)-\lambda)\psi_n\|
\rightarrow 0.
$$
We derive the contradiction.

Comment: The proof sounds reasonable to me, but those notes are really dense and hard to read. They should be cleaned up a little bit and be a bit more explicit in some cases.